# ASPxFileManager is not working. Script errors occur

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

ihave a dev ex file manager control in my aspx page .
I have set the image folder to the control but the file manager control is disabled.
below is my aspx code file.

```
    <dx:ASPxFileManager ID="fileManager" runat="server" Width="700px" Height="500px">
 <Settings RootFolder="~\ImageSlider" ThumbnailFolder="~\ImageSlider\products" 
      AllowedFileExtensions=".jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .rtf, .txt, .avi, .png, .mp3, .xml, .doc, .pdf" InitialFolder="~\ImageSlider\products" />
    <SettingsFileList View="Thumbnails">
    </SettingsFileList>
 <SettingsEditing AllowCreate="True" AllowDelete="True" AllowMove="True" AllowRename="True" />
    <SettingsToolbar ShowDownloadButton="True" />
    <SettingsUpload UseAdvancedUploadMode="True">
        <AdvancedModeSettings EnableMultiSelect="True" />
    </SettingsUpload>
 <SettingsPermissions>
      <AccessRules>
          <dx:FileManagerFileAccessRule Edit="Allow" Browse="Allow" Path="System" />
      </AccessRules>
 </SettingsPermissions>
```

The control is showing along with the folder but on clicking the folder no images are showing

Is throwing three errors in javascript

1- Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'SetStyles'

2-Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'OnFolderClick' of undefined DXR.axd?r=1_109-Qcan7:2074

3- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'OnToolbarItemClick' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the **ASPxHttpHandlerModule** is missing in the Web.config:

[Why DevExpress ASP.NET controls scripts and styles may not work?](http://www.devexpress.com/kbid=KA18691)